# Change URL (from other thread?) in a Java SWT Browser

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, browser, swt

In my Java program I have a main class which starts two threads:

- `Browserwindow` (`JFrame` with `SWT browser`)
- `Pagecyclecontroller` (class which cycles through a list of pages)

My main class notices when the `Pagecyclecontroller` updates its current URL, but I cannot tell my `Browserwindow` to change its page.

I first guess was a public method (in `Browserwindow`), `setURL`, `this.browser.setURL(..);` but it didn't work.

I am not very farmiliar with `SWT Browser`, it seems to loop its thread in this section:

```
...
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed() && frame.isVisible()) {  
  if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
     display.sleep();
  }
}
display.dispose();
frame.dispose();
```

If I change any of this (e.g. add `browser.setURL(...)`) nothing works at all...
Where and when do I change the URL in the browser itself? How can other classes change it?

Comment: Before starting the UI thread? Or somewhere in your UI-Class. There must be also some kind of "listener" where you can listen to the "open" or "started" event. There you could also change the url. I suggest reading some SWT Howto guides to get started. google will help you

Comment: I implemented the Pagecyclecontroller Observerable and Browserwindow as an Observer, call for "update" in my window works until I try to change the URL.. "org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access"

Comment: It seems you are mostly using SWT, so why the `JFrame`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update the GUI from a non-UI-thread. Read this:

[Why do I get an invalid thread access exception?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_do_I_get_an_invalid_thread_access_exception%3F)

The solution is to use `Display#asyncExec()`:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do any work that updates the screen
        // e.g., call browser.setURL(...);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep! "Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {...}" in my update method was the key! Thanks